# F# trim null chars

Tags: f#, null

I have a string recieved from a web socket:

```
let websocket = new ClientWebSocket()
let source = new CancellationTokenSource()
let buffer = ArraySegment(Array.zeroCreate 32)  

do! websocket.ConnectAsync(url, source.Token) 
do! websocket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, source.Token) 

let str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString buffer.Array

let trim1 = Regex.replace str "\0" String.Empty  // result is empty string
let trim2 = Regex.replace str "\\0" String.Empty // result is empty string
let trim3 = str.TrimEnd [| '\\'; '0' |]          // result is untouched
```

I am obviously trying to trim the excess null chars

In the debugger the value for str is "{\"type\":\"hello\"}\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"

When printed it looks like: {"type":"hello"} which makes sense, the symbols are being interpreted properly.

I seem to not be able to do this simple task in f#, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using ASCII escaping will do the trick:

```fs
let trim3 = str.TrimEnd [| '\x00' |]
```

You could also escape it with the unicode escape sequence:

```fs
let trim3 = str.TrimEnd [| '\u0000' |]
```

Your regular expression version does not work because the proper way to represent a null character in a regular expression is by [ASCII escaping using `"\x00"`, or unicode escaping using `"\u0000"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Odd, but it worked. Probably more consise as `str.TrimEnd '\u0000'` Why does the ascii version not work?

Comment: `[| '\\'; '0' |]` is not an escape sequence. It is an array with two separate characters: a forward slash and a zero. `\u0000' is an escape sequence for a single character: unicode null.

Comment: Sure, but I still would have thought the first regex.replace would have worked

Comment: In a regex, `"\0"` is not the proper way to escape a null character. See my edited answer

Comment: `Array.takeWhile ((<>) 0uy) >> Encoding.ASCII.GetString` is an alternate solution that can be faster if generally the text is short and the sequence of trailing nulls is long. Otherwise it tends to be slower.

Comment: Another way to represent the null char is `'\000'`. For some reason, the usual `'\0'`is not valid in F#.